# Is there any way to upload files via postman into a GraphQL API?

Tags: file, graphql, upload, postman

Currently I'm using Altair to upload files (in my case it's just for images) to my GraphQL API. However, all my other routes are stored in postman and it'd be nice if I could use just one application - Postman - for everything.

In Altair I can simply select an image and store that as a variable that I put as the value for my GraphQL Upload field.

Does anyone know if Postman supports that (or a similiar) feature?

Thank you!

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You can use Form-Data to do this.

Key: Operations (this is for the query / mutation )

```
{"query":"mutation updateAvatar($avatar:Upload!) {\n  updateAvatar(avatar: $avatar)\n}"}
```

Key: map ( this is to map the files to your query / mutation )

```
{"0": ["variables.avatar"]}
```

Key: 0 ( upload your image/file etc )

[image: postman]

Comment: Perfect, that works! I was wondering where you could get the 'select file prompt', but i eventually found it. It's kind of hidden as you need to hover over the key field to change it from 'Text' to 'File'. Thank you!

Comment: operations is not being detected by graphql for me. I get the error 
```
Bad POST multipart request: no part named "graphql" or "query"
```

Comment: I get this error "KeyError at / graphql /
'variables' "
Can you tell me why? 
https://prnt.sc/yu73z9 - error

Comment: In my case `{"0": ["varilables.avatar"]}` is only populating `variables.avatar` with the value `"0"` (and not with the file we used as its content). Do you have suggestions?

Comment: `varilables` seems like a typo

Comment: I have tried the solution provided here but I got the error `POST body missing, invalid Content-Type, or JSON object has no keys.` any idea on this?

Comment: this worked for me with [graphql-spring-boot](https://github.com/graphql-java-kickstart/graphql-spring-boot)

Comment: @EmadBaqeri I had the same problem and this worked for me https://stackoverflow.com/a/69607115/4984903.

Comment: For graphene and django users: you would find the upload contents of the mutation in `info.context.FILES`

Comment: How would you do to add others variables? E.g. filename, prefix, etc.

Comment: This gives me the issue "message": "The variables are expected to mutable at this point." for hotchocolate, it can be fixed if you add on "variables" behind the mutation. Refer to Javi answer below if anybody meets with the same issue.

Answer (score 6):

Answer from @Brad Larson is correct. But contains a typo:

You should have `{"0":["variables.file"]}` instead of `"[variables.file]"`

(Sorry I don't have enough reputation to comment)

Answer (score 4):

The above solution didn't work for me but helped as a base.

I've inspected other GraphQL server requests in my browser and tried emulating them.

This is how it works for me:

[image: Postman screenshot]

My server runs Django with Graphene, the difference may be there (?) I guess

Comment: Could you please share the content of the query as well please? In my case `profile_picture` is not populating the query variables and `query` is not being passed to graphene/django. I have to use `operations` as in the other answer (but `map` is not populating the query variables either).

Comment: btw, same thing works if you use Phoenix + Absinthe (Elixir)

Comment: What is the _query_ data that you put as the value? The screenshot doesn't make it clear how the file input (variable) is defined in the query string. Thanks.

Comment: This answer is useless if you are not showing the content of `query`

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue using `graphene-file-upload==1.2.2` as the upload handler and found it extremely complex to prepare the correct payload as the request included additional parameters to the upload file, so I hope this helps:[image]

This is the `curl` equivalent request for reference:

```
curl --location --request POST '<REDACTED>/graphql' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer <REDACTED>' \
--form '0=@"/home/user/Downloads/Five.pdf"' \
--form 'map="{\"0\": [\"variables.data.attachments\"]}"' \
--form 'operations="{
    \"query\": \"mutation AddPOAttachments($data: AddProductAttachmentsInput!) { add_product_attachments(data: $data) { attachments { id url purpose file_info { name type size_in_bytes} __typename } __typename }}\",
    \"variables\":
    {
        \"data\":
        {
            \"sku\": \"123456sku\",
            \"attachments\": null,
            \"purpose\": \"Test\"
        }
    }
}"'
```

Comment: The correct answer gave me the error: "message": "The variables are expected to mutable at this point." for hotchocolate. Using this answer it solves the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Postman was unable to do this, but I found another one called [`Altair`](https://altairgraphql.dev/). See [this](https://www.xkoji.dev/blog/working-with-file-uploads-using-altair-graphql/) blog that describes how to use it for file uploads. You can even see a glimpse of how it is done in the screenshot below:

[image: screenshot]
*Image taken from https://altairgraphql.dev/*

Answer (score -1):

you can use form-data for the same

[image]

you have add the below line to your graphql schema file

```
scalar Upload

type Mutation {
uploadFloorMap(floorMapImage: Upload!) : String
}
```

please add the below maven dependecies and modify your code to add new configuration

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.graphql-java-kickstart</groupId>
        <artifactId>graphql-java-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>14.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.graphql-java/graphql-java-extended-scalars -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.graphql-java</groupId>
        <artifactId>graphql-java-extended-scalars</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

add configuration code

```
import graphql.kickstart.servlet.apollo.ApolloScalars;
import graphql.schema.GraphQLScalarType;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class GraphQLConfiguration {

@Bean
public GraphQLScalarType uploadScalarDefine() {
return ApolloScalars.Upload;
 }
}
```